# opencart mini cart doesn't auto update when clicked add to cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart, shopping-cart

There is a problem with the mini cart for opencart on the header. I tried some solutions through the internet but none of the solutions worked and some of the solutions are just the same with code I have.

When I clicked add to cart of a product, the minicart doesn't update, but when I clicked the minicart, the cotents will load and that's the time it will update the mini cart. How to auto update the minicart without clicking it?

Thanks.

Here are the codes: 
module/cart.tpl

```
<div class="heading"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart "></i> <div class="cart-inner"> <h4><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h4> <a><span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></a> </div> </div>
```

view/javascript/common.js

```
$('#cart > .heading a').live('click', function() {

        $('#cart').addClass('active');



        $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');



        $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {

            $(this).removeClass('active');

        });

    });
```

Comment: show us your code and what you've tried

Comment: @jiboulex I've tried this one - http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=68714 but when I checked the mention files, they are just the same.

Comment: here is the cart code: <div class="heading">
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart "></i>
  <div class="cart-inner">
   <h4><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h4>
   <a><span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></a>
  </div>
 </div> @jiboulex

Comment: common.js code - $('#cart > .heading a').live('click', function() {

  $('#cart').addClass('active');

  

  $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');

  

  $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {

   $(this).removeClass('active');

  });

 }); @jiboulex

Comment: Edit your question to put it your code

Comment: Did you check your response in your console?

Comment: Yes. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3)" thats the only thing I saw in the console. @hardiksolanki

Comment: Question, edited. @jiboulex

Comment: Put your `cart.tpl` code inside `<div id="cart"></div>`.

Comment: It's already inside a div with an id = "cart" and class = "clearfix" @hardiksolanki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to host a [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) file at the root of the remote domain that grants permission to the local domain (or, as in this example, everyone):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

This file must always be at the root of the remote domain, e.g., http://example.com/crossdomain.xml .